# How to create a generic class instance from an arbitary object

Tags: delphi, generics

I define a generic class:

```
TContainer<T> = class
private
  FValue: T;
public
  constructor Create(aValue: T);
end;

constructor TContainer<T>.Create(aValue: T);
begin
  FValue := aValue;
end;
```

And I may use as follow:

```
var o: TContainer<TButton>;
begin
  o := TContainer<TButton>.Create(Button1);
  ShowMessage(o.ClassName);
end;
```

Next, I define a factory method to create a TContainer instance based on arbitary object class's type:

```
function CreateContainer(o: TObject): TObject;
begin
  Result := TContainer<o.ClassType>.Create;   // Fail: Undeclared identifier: 'TContainer'
end;
```

And invoke as this:

```
procedure TForm1.SomeEvent(Sender: TObject);
var o: TObject;
begin
  o := CreateContainer(Sender);
  ShowMessage(o.ClassName);
end;
```

My problem is how to implement `function CreateContainer(o: TObject): TObject` to return property `TContainer<T>` instance?

Comment: Generics are resolved at compile-time and you are trying to use run-time info (`o.ClassType`) with generics.

Comment: Can I use RTTI to make it works?

Comment: No. You cannot use runtime info to create a generic type.

Comment: You can use RTTI with generics. For instance a generic method can use RTTI to learn about the runtime type.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Can you show me some example?

Comment: Your real problem here is that unless you instantiate a generic type at compile time then it won't exist and RTTI won't help

Comment: It looks a little as though you might be reinventing TValue. You probably can't solve your problem as you try in the Q. What to do I cannot say. What is the underlying problem?

Comment: My problem is simple. I just want to create an instance of a generic class from TObject descendant.  What if I create registration repository to let compile know the generic type at compile time. For example: `Register<TButton>`, `Register<TStringList>`.  Will it helps?

Comment: There's no point at all in using generics if you don't know the type at compile time. I don't understand your problem, your solution isn't going to yield anything useful. You should explain the problem more fully. In the question.

Comment: As David Heffernan says, using generics is pointless.  All they do for you is to provide compile time type checking.  What you are trying to do should be done with a non-generic TList derivative potentially supporting some runtime type checking.